# mysql showing different data between user

Tags: mysql

I recently migrate my mysql to another server,
after migration, something weird.

When I use mysql as remote host:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h remote
mysql> select id from People order by id desc limit 10;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 941 |
| 940 |
| 939 |
| 938 |
| 937 |
| 936 |
| 935 |
| 934 |
| 933 |
| 932 |
+-----+
```

But when I use from localhost:

```
$ mysql -u root -p 
mysql> select id from People order by id desc limit 10;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 939 |
| 938 |
| 937 |
| 936 |
| 935 |
| 934 |
| 933 |
| 932 |
| 931 |
| 930 |
+-----+
```

Query result is missing 2 rows!

I also check the PRIVILEGES:

for remote case, it shows

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@example.com                                                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'example.com' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '521f3dd02c6d22f8' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

for localhost, it's have same privileges,

```
mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone help me why the query result is different between user@host?

Comment: could be that  id sequence is different .? . in one case is advanced  by two  ?  ..

Comment: i found out the reason, its because the table crash in some reason... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
I finally found why.

It's seems this table crash in some reason and need to repair
I goto mysql data dir and repair by these command:

```
$ myisamchk -r People
- recovering (with sort) MyISAM-table 'People'
Data records: 703
- Fixing index 1
Data records: 705
```

from the output can see the missing 2 record is back~~

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not commit your transaction. When using InnoDB tables and having the implicit-transaction setting activated, you first have to cast a `commit` in your 1st client to make your changes visible to all users.